# Cross Table Left Join, Django ORM

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have the following models:

```
class TradeDetails(models.Model):
    created_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(db_column='CREATED_TIMESTAMP', primary_key=True)
    trade_name = models.CharField(db_column='TRADE_NAME', max_length=45)
    trade_image = models.CharField(db_column='TRADE_IMAGE', max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'TRADE_DETAILS'


class TradeNotifications(models.Model):
    client_id = models.CharField(db_column='CLIENT_ID', primary_key=True, max_length=15)
    created_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(db_column='CREATED_TIMESTAMP')
    updated_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(db_column='UPDATED_TIMESTAMP', blank=True, null=True)
    platform_notification = models.IntegerField(db_column='PLATFORM_NOTIFICATION', blank=True, null=True)
    sms_notification = models.IntegerField(db_column='SMS_NOTIFICATION', blank=True, null=True)
    email_notification = models.IntegerField(db_column='EMAIL_NOTIFICATION', blank=True, null=True)
    caller_notification = models.IntegerField(db_column='CALLER_NOTIFICATION', blank=True, null=True)
    caller_id = models.IntegerField(db_column='CALLER_ID', blank=True, null=True)
    client_confirmation = models.IntegerField(db_column='CLIENT_CONFIRMATION', blank=True, null=True)
    device_id = models.CharField(db_column='DEVICE_ID', max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
    platform = models.CharField(db_column='PLATFORM', max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
    ip_address = models.CharField(db_column='IP_ADDRESS', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    expired = models.IntegerField(db_column='EXPIRED', blank=True, null=True)
    trade_sent = models.IntegerField(db_column='TRADE_SENT', blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'TRADE_NOTIFICATIONS'
        unique_together = (('client_id', 'created_timestamp'),)
```

I want to perform a left join on another table on the same db using the following sql query:

> SELECT TRADE_DETAILS.TRADE_NAME FROM TRADE_NOTIFICATIONS LEFT JOIN
>   TRADE_DETAILS ON TRADE_NOTIFICATIONS.CREATED_TIMESTAMP =
>   TRADE_DETAILS.CREATED_TIMESTAMP

Is there a more Django-Like way of doing this or should I just go with raw
sql?

Upon reading some answers I tried to do this :

```
TradeNotifications.objects.using('tradenotifications').all().values_list('trade_name', 'trade_details_created_timestamp')
```

but it raised an error :
`django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'trade_name' into field. Choices are: caller_id, caller_notification,`

Answer (score 0):

You can't join tables without some relationship between models such as foreign key with Django ORM. There must be a relationship between the models.

This relationship doesn't have to be in the db, it's enough if it's defined in the models, but I don't think this is possible with your TradeDetails and TradeNotifications models. It could be possible with your `client_id` field; you'd change it from `CharField()` to `ForeignKey()`. This is especially useful in cases when you only read from the database and you reverse engineer it and use them as non-managed models.